# Use certificates in Docker container of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, registry

I've started Jenkins in a Docker container by mounting the Docker sockets. So now I'm able to perform docker commands on my Jenkins. But the specific folders of Docker aren't in my container. (Just mounted the sockets).

Now I need to use certs to access my Docker registry. The path of the certs needs to be: `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.com:5000/ca.crt`
But this does not exist in my Jenkins which just contains the bin and run folders of Docker.

What's the best way to connect the certificates for my Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

The way I'm doing it (for my SSL web server, but I think the principle is the same) is simply mounting the cert directory with `-v`.

E.g.:

```
docker run -v /etc/pki:/etc/pki:ro -P 443:443 mycontainer
```

Seems to work quite nicely (although it helps loads if you can wildcard the hostname, so your container doesn't need to "know" which host it's running on)